# Google script stops halfway

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

the following script was just mean to alternate the BG color for a sheet when RESET was entered into the first cell. This works up until the high 400's but the sheet has 662 rows. Any idea why it stop short, I do ask to go to `lastRow` and have subbed that with the value 662 with the same results.

```
function onEdit() 
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();

  var resetCells = sheet.getRange("A1");
  var resetCell = resetCells.getValues();

  if (resetCell == "RESET")
  {
    sheet.getRange("A1").clearContent();

    var x;
    var y = 0;
    for (x = 1; x <= lastRow; x++)
    {
     var Location = sheet.getRange(x, 1);
     var currentCell = Location.getValues();
     var cell = ss.getActiveCell();
     var range = sheet.getRange(x, 1, 1, lastColumn);
     if (currentCell == "")
      {
        y++;
      }

     if (currentCell != "")
      {
        if (y%2 == 0)
        {
          range.setBackgroundRGB(225, 125, 75);
        }
        else
        {
          range.setBackgroundRGB(75, 125, 225);
        }
      }

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Almost certainly your script runs too long. Simple triggers can only execute for 30 seconds; review the Apps Script guide to triggers for other restrictions.